# How Can I Achieve This in Using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a requirement that is

I have a table with partner and event details, each partner having number of events.Now i need to get the event details based on partnerid, means

```
 partner1->event1
 partner2->event1
 .......
 partnern->event1

 Partner1->event2
 partner2->event2
 ........
 partnern->event2

 ...
 .....
partner1->eventn
partner2->eventn
......
```

Here each partner having their own number of events.Please give me suggetions, I am using mysql

Here is my table sructure

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `eventid` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `partnerid` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventid`),
  KEY `partnerid` (`partnerid`),
  KEY `locationid` (`locationid`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`partnerid`) REFERENCES `partnerprofile` (`userid`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`locationid`) REFERENCES `location` (`locatinid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Show your table structure.
Column-names and one or two sample row data atleast.

Comment: Here i added my table structure, Here i have total data in one table only, need to sort rows as like my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that clear with your requirement. Anyway giving a try.

After you have mastered the basics of MySQL, take the next step and take on Aggregate Functions. `Group BY` is good for retrieving information about a group of data. If you only had one product of each type, then `GROUP BY` would not be all that useful.

`GROUP BY` only shines when you have many similar things. For example, if you have a number of partners of the same type, and you want to find out some statistical information like the minimum, maximum, or other top-level info, you would use `GROUP BY`.

Here is the updated solution:

```
SELECT A.`event_id` AS 'Event(ID)', B.`partner_names` AS 'Partners' FROM `event` A
JOIN
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( P.`partner_name`) AS 'partner_names'
               FROM (SELECT `partner_name` FROM information_schema.columns
               WHERE table_name='partnerprofile') as P) FROM `partnerprofile` B
GROUP BY A.`partnerid`
```

Here assume that `partner_name` is the name field in the `partnerprofile` table.

And the expected output is:

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
|   Event(ID)   | Partners                                   |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
|    event_001  | Partener1, Partener2, Partener4            |
|    event_002  | Partener2, Partener3, Partener9            |
|    event_003  | Partener15                                 |
|    event_004  | Partener5, Partener7, Partener9            |
|    _________  | _________, _________                       |
|    _________  | _________                                  |
|    _________  | _________, _________ _________, _________  |
|    _________  | _________, _________,                       |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thankyou for quick reply, i want to display events like for example if there is 5 partners and each partner having 2 or 3 events per each, now i want to display 1st event for all partners,then 2nd for all like so...

Comment: @kondapaka: This is all I understood from your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

I think an INNER JOIN should work. something like:

> SELECT * FROM event INNER JOIN partner ON event.partnerID = partner.partnerID

Comment: Why need an 'INNER JOIN' for this simple requirement?

Comment: there is no need to use innerhjoin, i had all data in event table only